# Download Image from URL not end with .jpeg

Tags: image, url, download, jpeg

Can help me to how to download an image from api url link not end with .jpeg as like below

https://www.upiqrcode.com/upi-qr-code-api-jpeg/v01/?vpa=9879991234@paytm&payee=mysoftware&amount=2608&website=www.mysite.com

and Image name Myimg.jpeg and should save in a folder D:\MyImage

It can possible by cmd batch? **for Windows OS**

Waiting for Experts reply, please.

Thanks & Regards

Comment: Also help, if any other alternatives (ready exe) to download image from dynamic url not ends with extension (jpg/jpeg etc.)

Answer (score 0):

on mac:
`curl --output YOUR_FILE_NAME.jpg https://www.upiqrcode.com/upi-qr-code-api-jpeg/v01/?vpa=9879991234@paytm`

on linux:
`wget -O YOUR_FILE_NAME.jpg https://www.upiqrcode.com/upi-qr-code-api-jpeg/v01/?vpa=9879991234@paytm`

on windows, looks like you can download curl https://curl.haxx.se/windows/

EDIT:
You can also use wget for Windows
http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm

Comment: Thanks for instant reply, i need to use in Windows OS, kindly help, is above line (curl --) use to make batch file for windows,

Comment: please help as i am blind for cmd batch

Comment: Please help, any experts focus on it

Comment: if curl (unknown for me) is necessary to install for windows, can anyone provide its exe instead of source code files. also help on it.